# Tailwind space-4-x -> first item not getting the space applied

Tags: html, tailwind-css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="flex space-x-4 flex-col">
      <div>Item</div>
      <div>Item</div>
      <div>Item</div>
      <div>Item</div>
      <div>Item</div>
      <div>Item</div>
      <div>Item</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is my markdown. It should be reproducible. My Problem is that the first item does not get the spacing applied. Every other item does get the space applied. Am I doing something wrong here? I want ALL the items to have space.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
<div class="ml-4">
   <div>Item</div>
   <div>Item</div>
   ...etc.
</div>
```

---

Nice nuance find. `space-x-4` is behaving as expected - it's for putting space **between items horizontally**, so the intended use case is all your divs are on the same line.

[image]

`space-x-4` is just applying left and right margin to all items after the first

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [gap](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/gap) by simply doing `gap-4`.

As per the [docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/space#limitations), space-x has limitations.

> These utilities are really just a shortcut for adding margin to
> all-but-the-first-item in a group, and aren’t designed to handle
> complex cases like grids, layouts that wrap, or situations where the
> children are rendered in a complex custom order rather than their
> natural DOM order.
>
> For those situations, it’s better to use the gap utilities when
> possible, or add margin to every element with a matching negative
> margin on the parent.

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/gap